# Correlation between hospital units and length of stay

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, categorical-data, coefficients

I am trying to determine if the hospital I work at should open a new unit for admissions. I intend to do this by correlating patient assigned unit and length of stay in days.

So far, I have determined that the continuous dependent variable (length of stay in days) should be log transformed, as well as the continuous age variable. Unit is categorical and contains 7 categories (unit 65, unit 66, unit 67, unit 75, unit 76, unit 77, unit 94). Gender is standard 0=male and 1=female.

My regression equation is as follows:

`log_glm <- glm(log(days)~ gender + log(age) + unit, family=gaussian, data=data2022)`

Model Summary:

```
glm(formula = log(days) ~ gender + log(age) + unit, family = gaussian, 
    data = data2022)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-4.3606  -0.6712   0.0011   0.7146   2.8338  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   0.7416     0.9994   0.742 0.459064    
gender        0.3257     0.2082   1.564 0.119566    
log(age)      1.3809     0.2353   5.870 2.17e-08 ***
unitunit_66   0.1329     0.2994   0.444 0.657717    
unitunit_67   1.2518     0.3334   3.755 0.000237 ***
unitunit_75  -1.8108     0.3067  -5.903 1.84e-08 ***
unitunit_76   0.2797     0.3120   0.896 0.371355    
unitunit_77  -0.3540     0.3178  -1.114 0.266803    
unitunit_94   0.1876     0.5350   0.351 0.726339    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 1.145772)

    Null deviance: 429.95  on 181  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 198.22  on 173  degrees of freedom
  (14 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 552.03

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

All units at this hospital house patients with different needs. Is it appropriate to "compare" each unit in the summary output to the reference unit when all units are unique? Is this interpretation correct:

*Unit 67 is statistically significant at the 0.05 level. The coefficient is 1.2518, so being assigned to unit 67 is associated with a length of stay in days 249.6631% ((exp(1.2518)-1*100) higher on average than those assigned to unit 65.*

Doubting myself because that result seemed too high and interpretation incorrect, I tried a model with dummy variables for unit:

`log_glm_age <- glm(log(days)~ gender + log(age) + unit_65 + unit_66 + unit_67 + unit_75 + unit_76 + unit_77 + unit_94, family=gaussian, data=data2022)`

With output:

```
glm(formula = log(days) ~ gender + log(age) + unit_65 + unit_66 + 
    unit_67 + unit_75 + unit_76 + unit_77 + unit_94, family = gaussian, 
    data = data2022)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-4.3606  -0.6712   0.0011   0.7146   2.8338  

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.92919    1.10243   0.843 0.400475    
gender       0.32568    0.20819   1.564 0.119566    
log(age)     1.38094    0.23525   5.870 2.17e-08 ***
unit_65     -0.18755    0.53500  -0.351 0.726339    
unit_66     -0.05465    0.52964  -0.103 0.917936    
unit_67      1.06427    0.55764   1.909 0.057979 .  
unit_75     -1.99832    0.53701  -3.721 0.000268 ***
unit_76      0.09213    0.54694   0.168 0.866435    
unit_77     -0.54160    0.52780  -1.026 0.306252    
unit_94           NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 1.145772)

    Null deviance: 429.95  on 181  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 198.22  on 173  degrees of freedom
  (14 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 552.03

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

But I am having doubts interpreting this. Since each patient is only admitted to one unit, is it appropriate to have all units in the model?

I don't know if it's because I am the only analyst in the entire hospital and can't discuss this with anyone who understands or if I'm having a weird day, but I can't figure out what is correct right now and could use some guidance.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have questions about interpreting results from a statistical model, you should ask for statistical advice at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: @MrFlick thank you! I will post there.